# How to use a variable inside case insensitive regex in Dart

Tags: regex, dart

I would like to find how many matches of a particular word are inside a string of text. I want the word that I am searching for to be provided as a variable rather than a String. The search should be case insensitive.

I can get it working with a variable:

```
String text = "here is some text and SOME more words";
String word = "some";

RegExp pattern = RegExp(word);
Iterable matches = pattern.allMatches(text);
print(matches.length);  // prints 1 but want 2.
```

But I am not sure how to add case insensitivity. The JavaScript style `/i` and `RegExp(word, "i")` do not work.

The Dart docs show there is a property called `isCaseSensitive` but it is shown as `read-only`.
https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you can set `isCaseSensitive`. It is a named parameter that you can see in the Constructor of the `RegExp` method.
https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html

```
String text = "here is some text and SOME more words";
String word = "some";

RegExp pattern = RegExp(word, caseSensitive: false);
Iterable matches = pattern.allMatches(text);
print(matches.length);  // correctly prints 2.
```